# building decorator with token authentication and functools.wraps

Tags: python, authentication, kivy, token, decorator

i am building a kivy app that does APIs requests.
`get_token()` function runs first when app is launched to get all the necessary info, dicts, vars etc. After 30 min token gets expired, app has a buttons that on_press it will send request calls to the server, if the token is expired it wont work. I am trying to build a decorator `@use_token` that will check if simple request gets executed and receives response 200 Success code, if success: return(decorated function) else: calling `get_token` that will refresh token, and returning decorated function. A whole concept works, prints work at every possible block of code in every function, but when after 30 min token is expired, `refresh_token()` calls for `get_token()` inside the if statement, prints are still working but returned decorated function doesnt send requests, it prints test strings but doesnt do the main thing. That tells me that function `get_token()` executes inside if statement but doesn't update token information...

FIRST FUNCTION, RUNS ONES AT START:

```
def get_token():
    url_token = "http://server.com"
    payload = "{" \
              "\n  \"grantType\": \"password\"," \
              "\n  \"password\": \"string\"," \
              "\n  \"refreshToken\": \"string\"," \
              "\n  \"token\": \"string\"," \
              "\n  \"username\": \"admin\"" \
              "\n}"
    headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'api_key': ''
        }
    global readyToken
    readyToken = requests.request("POST", url_token, headers=headers, data=payload).json()['token']
    print("Getting a NEW TOKEN!")
get_token()
```

DECORATOR FUNCTION:

```
def use_token(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def refresh_token(*args):
        url_check = "simplerequest.com"
        response = requests.request("PUT", url_check, headers=HEADERS)
        print("This print from url_check block "+str(response))
        str_response = str(response)
        if '401' in str_response:
            print("401 found, Token is Expired, refreshing with get_token")
            get_token()
        else:
            print("200 Code, success, passing, leaving else statement")
            pass
        print("emptying str_response and calling for decorated function:")
        str_response = ""
        return func(*args)
    return refresh_token
```

DECORATED FUNCTION:

```
global URL_QC, HEADERS

URL_QC = "www.server.com"
HEADERS = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'api_key': readyToken
}


@use_token
def change_channel(self, display_mac, ch_number):
    print("Hello from DECORATED function!!!")
    payload = "{\"deviceIds\": [" + str(display_mac) + "],\"menu\": \"save_sch_channel\", \"productType\": \"string\", \"value\":" + str(ch_number) + "}"
    response = requests.request("PUT", URL_QC, headers=HEADERS, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the `HEADERS` variable when the `readyToken` changes.

```py
HEADERS = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'api_key': readyToken
}
```

In python, strings are passed by value.  So here, you are only setting `HEADERS['api_key']` to the current value of `readyToken` once.  If you change `readyToken` later, the `HEADERS` is not updated because it only retains the original value of `readyToken`.

This can be solved by simply updating `readyToken` in the `HEADERS` every time it changes:

```py
def get_token():
    url_token = "http://server.com"
    payload = {
        "grantType": "password",
        "password":  "string",
        "refreshToken": "string",
        "token": "string",
        "username": "admin"
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        "api_key": ""
    }
    response = requests.post(url_token, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(f'Got Response: {response.json()}')
    global readyToken
    readyToken = response.json()['token']

    # We also need to update headers!
    global HEADERS
    HEADERS['api_key'] = readyToken
```

Even better, if you are only using readyToken in the `HEADERS`, remove the readyToken variable entirely and simply update the global `HEADERS` variable:

```
def get_token():
    ...
    response = requests.post(url_token, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(f'Got Response: {response.json()}')
    global HEADERS
    HEADERS['api_key'] = response.json()['token']
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much on suggestion number 1, implemented! I edited the last block of code and added global var definitions, i should have added it here from the beginning, kinda important ). And your 2nd point is totally right, variable ```readyToken``` doesn't get updated when elif == 401 block will be triggered it will call get_token function and in my understanding it should update variable ```readyToken``` but it does not, i am pretty sure we are close to solution )

Comment: @jarrett.rus26 updated my answer, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alfa Q thank you so much, all your guesses and fixes was right! I do use token only in header, therefore i got read of readyToken and put token expression right into 'api_key' value. I also restructured the code and made a class implementing all your fixes:

token.py:

```
class Token:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url_check = "www.check.com"
        self.url_token = "www.server.com"
        self.payload = "{" \
                  "\n  \"grantType\": \"password\"," \
                  "\n  \"password\": \"password\"," \
                  "\n  \"refreshToken\": \"string\"," \
                  "\n  \"token\": \"string\"," \
                  "\n  \"username\": \"admin\"" \
                  "\n}"
        self.headers_token = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'api_key': self.get_token()
            }

    def get_token(self):
        return requests.post(self.url_token, headers=self.headers, data=self.payload).json()['token']

    def use_token(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def refresh_token(*args):
            response = requests.put(self.url_check, headers=self.headers_token)
            print("This print from url_check block: " + str(response))
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print('Status 200 | Token OK - No refresh necessary')
                return func(*args)
            elif response.status_code == 401:
                print('Status 401 | Token is Expired - Refreshing')
                self.get_token()
                return func(*args)
            else:
                print(f'Status {response.status_code} | Error Occurred')
                print("Print from REFRESH_TOKEN")
        return refresh_token
```

main.py:

```
@token.use_token
def change_channel(self, display_mac, ch_number):
    print("Hello from DECORATED function!!!")
    payload = "{\"deviceIds\": [" + str(display_mac) + "],\"menu\": \"save_sch_channel\", \"productType\": \"string\", \"value\":" + str(ch_number) + "}"
    response = requests.request("PUT", URL_QC, headers=token.headers_token, data=payload)
    print(response)
```

Comment: nice!  i'm glad to hear your problems were solved :)